# is there a difference between using built in Head component from nextjs and head tag from as jsx

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

I hope that this question is suitable for this comunity.
I am confused on how build in Head component in nextjs work.
My guess is that as a default nextjs creates metadata and Head replaces or add to it. However I am not sure what would happen if I create my own metadata not with buildIn Head but with a custom meta component like this:

```
<html len= {leng || "en"}>
<head>
///some data 
</head>
```

I guess it doesn't really matter but I want to learn the the need for a buildIn Head component.
also I want to be able to change language of the page and It seems easier with my custom component?

Comment: `next/head` is more idiomatic and it also provides additional functionality like deduping meta tags. "I want to be able to change language of the page" - that's done using the `<html>` element though, not through the `<head>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use regular `<head>` tag it will just print it as is. In the root level Layout component, such as in your example, it won't matter. But Next's component will help when you want to set `<head>` from sub components, so basically it will act like a reference for the head element in the page. You can read about other features of it in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head).